# Delphi - Show a multiline caption in the designer

Tags: delphi, multiline, word-wrap

I am replacing in runtime the `Caption` of several components to get a multiline `Caption`.

```
MySpeedButton.Caption := 'Line 1' + #13 + #10 + 'Line 2';
```

Is there a way to persuade Delphi to show a wordwrap also in the designer?

Comment: Delphi 10.2.3 - which string exactly do you add in the designer to be able to see the multiline caption?

Comment: Which Delphi version? I can enter a multiline caption for a TSpeedButton in 10.2 without any problems.

Comment: Just click on the 3-dotted button that appears once you enter the Edit to type your caption in.

Comment: I don't have such a button in the object inspector.

Comment: Must be from one of the add ins I use then, okay.

Comment: Any idea which one it could be? And we are talking about VCL?

Comment: Yes, VCL. Should be either GExperts or DDevExtensions.

Comment: I installed now both - but I still don't see a button to add a multiline caption.

Comment: Could also be Konopka Signature VCL Controls aka Raize Components.

Comment: @Uwe: I downloaded and installed now Konopka Signature VCL Controls. But these are only new components?! They don't change anything in the IDE? I still don't find that button which Sebastian was mentioning.

Comment: Raze Components install a couple of property editors, especially a `TRzCaptionPropertyEditor`. I am not sure though if that acts on all components with a `Caption` property. It should definitely work for any `TCustomLabel`.

Comment: Seems so whether only `TCustomLabel`has the multiline editor. But Sebastian wrote that he has it also for a `TSpeedButton`.

Comment: @Jens: If you are still looking for such feature, take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61724451/4528159)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the `caption` of a `TSpeedButton` to be multiline by editing the caption in `Text View` of the form:

```
  object SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 63
    Width = 113
    Height = 50
    Caption = 'Line 1Line 2'       // original caption
    Caption = 'Line 1'#10'Line 2'  // modified caption
  end
```

Note! You must add the two single quotes on both sides of the `#10`. Instead of `#10` you can use `#13` or both `#13#10`.

For an ordinary `TButton` you need to set the `WordWrap` property in addition to the above modification to the `Text View` of the form.

Comment: I tried already to use `'Line 1' + #13#10 + 'Line 2'` but I was looking for a 'normal' way.

Comment: Sorry @Jens, in your question you said you do that at runtime but want to see the wordwrap in the designer. If you want to see the multiline in *design view*, you have to do it as I said. There is no 'normal' way. Note, I said you have to add the CR or NL character in `Text View` of the form

Comment: You are correct - I wrote 'show'. But I had more in mind. I cannot set several captions at the same time. I also cannot easily copy and paste the multiline `Caption` from one component to another. I hoped/thought, that I can use something similar like the `&`character to start a word-wrap.

Comment: @Jens, there's nothing that prevents you from copying a caption from one button to another (or several other) one(s). The text view is just a text file with a special format, so it is crucial not to disturb the indenting of the lines.

Comment: When I copy and paste in the object inspector then only the first line is copied

Comment: I mentioned `Text View` twice in my answer, and I have referred to it twice before in these comments. For a final time, you need to deal with the task in `Text View` of the form. Do you know what `Text View` means? If not, press Alt-F12 to toggle between `Design View` and `Text View` of the form. BTW, you have not indicated which Delphi version you are using.

Comment: I know that you wrote text view. I also wrote that I was looking for a normal way. I have a dfm with 25k lines. I find components visually much faster than by searching within a text file. As far as I understand Sebastian and Uwe there exists a third party tool which allows me to edit directly. I only didn't find out which one it is. I wrote that I use 10.2.3 (second (now first) comment)

Comment: @Jens -  the answer is that you can only do this in text view regardless of what you're looking for. Unless you write your own property editor of course. 3rd party suggestions are off topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en)

After installing it, make sure the *String Caption Editor* is enabled and add `TSpeedButton.Caption` to the *Customize* section.

[image: CnPack options in the Delphi menu]

[image: Picture of the String Caption Editor enabled for the TSpeedButton.Caption property]

In the *Object Inspector* you will see a button edit which will allow you to set a multi line caption.

[image: Picture displaying how to set a multiline caption for the TSpeedButton.Caption property using hte String Caption Editor]

[image: Picture of a TSpeedButton with a multiline caption]